# Linq Error: InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression

Tags: linq

Get value out of DateTime column
if null to return String.Empty
else
DateTime.ToShortDateString

What am I doing wrong => query produced below:

```
var queryable = from p in Products
    select new {
               selldate = p.SellEndDate == null
                           ? string.Empty
                           : p.SellEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()  };
```

Error: InvalidOperationException: Could not translate expression 'Table(Product).Select(p => new <>f__AnonymousType0`1(selldate = IIF((p.SellEndDate = null), Invoke(value(System.Func`1[System.String])), p.SellEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString())))' into SQL and could not treat it as a local expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically what's happening here is that LINQ to SQL is taking your entire query and trying to convert it into something that SQL Server can understand. The problem, though, is that SQL Server has no concept of DateTime.ToShortDateString, so the conversion to SQL fails.

You'll have to change your query so that it just selects SellEndDate (which will get it as a `Nullable<DateTime>`) and then when you use the results of that query you can do the conversion to string. For example:

```
var list = (from p in Products
           select p.SellEndDate).ToList();

// calling ToList() above means we have the entire resultset in memory and
// no longer have to pass the query back to SQL Server

var stuff = from p in list select new
{ 
    selldate = p.SellEndDate == null ?
                   string.Empty :
                   p.SellEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString()
};
```

Comment: I got this done as :
 var queryable = from p in Products
      let Date = (p.SellEndDate.Value != null) ? p.SellEndDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : String.Empty
       select new
            {
            SellDate = Date
            };
it works.

Comment: Wow, it looks like it goes to SQL and comes back to c# when the time comes to execute functions like ToShortDateString.

Comment: You don't really need to call ToList() - you can just call AsEnumerable(). That's enough to force it to use local execution.

Comment: @Jon, will the execution be different when ToList is called vs AsEnumerable? I mean - does it fetch 1 record, come to c#, call the ToShort.., go back to SQL and repeat

Comment: @Jon yeah I must admit I wasn't sure about AsEnumerable. LINQ can be so "late-bound" that I often just call ToList() just to be sure. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`ToShortDateString` doesn't seem to have equivalent SQL translation.
Use `ToString` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If the date time field allows nulls:

```
from order in repository.Order
     select order.OrdShipDate == null ? "" : order.OrdShipDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).Month.ToString() + "/" + order.OrdShipDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).Day.ToString() + "/" + order.OrdShipDate.GetValueOrDefault(DateTime.Now).Year.ToString();
```

If the date time field doesn't allow nulls:

```
from order in repository.Order
     select order.OrdShipDate.Month.ToString() + "/" + order.OrdShipDate.Day.ToString() + "/" + order.OrdShipDate.Year.ToString();
```